# PHP: Getting array type

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a php function that someone can use to automatically detect if an array is an associative or not, apart from explictly checking the array keys?

Comment: I sense something wrong in your design. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It's not an uncommon need, especially when writing more generic, non application-specific code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Arrays: A good way to check if an array is associative or sequential?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-sequential)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

quoted from the official site:

> The indexed and associative array
>   types are the same type in PHP,

So the best solution I can think of is running on all the keys, or using array_keys,implode,is_numeric

Comment: Please see my comment below about comparing the original array to its array_values().

Answer (score 15):

My short answer: YES

Quicker and easier, IF you make the assumption that a "non-associative array" is indexed starting at 0:

```
if ($original_array == array_values($original_array))
```

Comment: I feel I have to continue because other answers that take longer are being voted up.

One does not have to examine the keys.  array_values() returns an integer-indexed array, thus if one compares the array in question with its array_values() and they are equal, the original array is a 0 based, integer indexed array.  It is the shortest, slickest way.  Try it out.

Comment: I agree, arrays that are not indexed *continuously starting at `0`* should be considered associative, since they can't be traversed reliably with the typical `for ($x++)` pattern. Hence this test is probably the best to use. It becomes sort of a philosophical debate though, as PHP arrays simply aren't one or the other. :)

Comment: I was just trying to pass on the quickest/slickest way I found to determine if the indices are 0 thru N without any kind of explicit inspection of the keys.<p>I _love_ PHP arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
function is_associative_array($array) {
    return (is_array($array) && !is_numeric(implode("", array_keys($array))));
}
```

Testing the keys works well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the discussions at [is_array](https://www.php.net/is_array).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Associative and indexed arrays are the same type in PHP. Indexed arrays are a subset of associative arrays where:

- The keys are only integers;
- They range from 0 to N-1 where N is the size of the array.

You can try and detect that if you want by using array_keys(), a sort and comparison with a range() result.