# How to check if array is list?

Tags: php, arrays, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Arrays: A good way to check if an array is associative or sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-sequential)

Hello :)

I was wondering what is the shortest (best) way to check if an array is

a list:
`array('a', 'b', 'c')`

or it's an associative array:
`array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd')`

fyi: I need this to make a custom `json_encode` function

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Arrays: A good way to check if an array is associative or sequential?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-sequential) Why do you need to build a custom `json_encode` function though? Are you on a PHP version that doesn't have it yet? There are pre-made packages for that case.

Comment: Implementations of `json_encode` are available for download, so maybe check them out and customize them? Here's one: http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Comment: @Pekka I need to be able to send javascript functions from the php file

Comment: not sure what you mean by that, but isn't that possible by wrapping some Javascript around a `json_encode` result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function is_assoc($array){
    return array_values($array)!==$array;
}
```

Note that it will also return TRUE if array is indexed but contains holes or doesn't start with 0, or keys aren't ordered. I usually prefer using this function because it gives best possible performance.
As an alternative for these cases I prefer this (just keep in mind that it's almost 4 times slower than above):

```
function is_assoc($array){
    return !ctype_digit( implode('', array_keys($array)) );
}
```

Using `ksort()` as Rinuwise commented is a bit slower.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work, if the array keys are not in order in the array. If this is not desired, it can be avoided by performing ksort() on the array prior the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I improved my answer with those cases.

Comment: if keys like "080" this will wrong. Example array('0'=>1, '08'=>2);