# Determine whether an array is associative (hash) or not

Tags: php, arrays, hash

I'd like to be able to pass an array to a function and have the function behave differently depending on whether it's a "list" style array or a "hash" style array. E.g.:

```
myfunc(array("One", "Two", "Three")); // works
myfunc(array(1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three")); also works, but understands it's a hash
```

Might output something like:

```
One, Two, Three
1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three
```

ie: the function does something differently when it "detects" it's being passed a hash rather than an array. Can you tell I'm coming from a Perl background where %hashes are different references from @arrays?

I believe my example is significant because we can't just test to see whether the key is numeric, because you could very well be using numeric keys in your hash.

I'm specifically looking to avoid having to use the messier construct of `myfunc(array(array(1=>"One"), array(2=>"Two"), array(3=>"Three")))`

Comment: Looking for something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-sequential

Comment: Interesting question. PHP unfortunately does not distinguish `array('a','b','c')` from `array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c')`...

Comment: PHP will always store numeric keys `array("1" => "1")` as integers. Can't detect that. You can only probe for continually growing keys to differentiate true lists from indexed arrays.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately it does not distinguish 'simple' arrays and those with numeric strings as keys (see my answer).

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/173400/287948

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Pulled right out of the kohana framework.

```
public static function is_assoc(array $array)
{
    // Keys of the array
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    // If the array keys of the keys match the keys, then the array must
    // not be associative (e.g. the keys array looked like {0:0, 1:1...}).
    return array_keys($keys) !== $keys;
}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed. I'm still taking this a little bit on faith.... but it works in my code, so thanks!

Comment: This fails for non-associative arrays that have been filtered, like [5 => 'foo'].

Comment: `array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1)`  as http://stackoverflow.com/a/173479/287948 ,

Comment: `[0 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3=>'c']` returns true with this method

Comment: also used by Laravel framework. (in Illuminate\Support\Arr class)

Answer (score 16):

[This benchmark](https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/1965669) gives 3 methods.

Here's a summary, **sorted from fastest to slowest**. For more informations, read the complete [benchmark here](https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/1965669).

**1. Using array_values()**

```php
function($array) {
    return (array_values($array) !== $array);
}
```

**2. Using array_keys()**

```php
function($array){
    $array = array_keys($array); return ($array !== array_keys($array));
}
```

**3. Using array_filter()**

```php
function($array){
    return count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string')) > 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be good to annotate this with the actual benchmark results in case the link goes stale. It's very important to note that the `array_filter` approach is orders of magnitude __slower__ than the others.

Comment: `[0 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3=>'c']` returns true for the first case.

Answer (score 7):

PHP treats all arrays as hashes, technically, so there is not an exact way to do this.  Your best bet would be the following I believe:

```
if (array_keys($array) === range(0, count($array) - 1)) {
   //it is a hash
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that was posted so I'll accept it, despite its inherent limitation of not accounting for non-sequential array indices. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-sequential has a lot more solutions, none of which are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP does not differentiate arrays where the keys are numeric strings from the arrays where the keys are integers in cases like the following:

```
$a = array("0"=>'a', "1"=>'b', "2"=>'c');
$b = array(0=>'a', 1=>'b', 2=>'c');

var_dump(array_keys($a), array_keys($b));
```

It outputs:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2)
}
array(3) {
    [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2)
}
```

(above formatted for readability)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to get keys of an array like below and check that if the key is not integer:

```
private function is_hash($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        return ! is_int($key);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is wrong to get array_keys of a hash array like below:

```
array_keys(array(
       "abc" => "gfb",
       "bdc" => "dbc"
       )
);
```

will output:

```
array(
       0 => "abc",
       1 => "bdc"
)
```

So, it is not a good idea to compare it with a range of numbers as mentioned in top rated answer. It will always say that it is a hash array if you try to compare keys with a range.

Comment: Walk me through your function, because there's something I'm missing. You have a foreach loop, but you return on the very first iteration of that loop! What's the point of the loop if you're just returning whether the first key is an integer? Perhaps you meant to set a flag to true and then in our loop if it IS an integer, set the flag to false?

Comment: otherwise you always get an integer value as an array key thats why!

Comment: This is closer to the real answer IMHO. Tom Auger has a point, though. I think it would be more like:

    private function is_hash($array) {
        foreach(array_keys($array) as $key) {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Being a little frustrated, trying to write a function to address all combinations, an idea clicked in my mind: parse `json_encode` result.

When a json string contains a curly brace, then it must contain an object!

Of course, after reading the solutions here, mine is a bit funny...
Anyway, I want to share it with the community, just to present an attempt to solve the problem from another prospective (more "visual").

```php
function isAssociative(array $arr): bool
    {
        // consider empty, and [0, 1, 2, ...] sequential
        if(empty($arr) || array_is_list($arr)) {
            return false;
        }

        // first scenario:
        // [  1  => [*any*] ]
        // [ 'a' => [*any*] ]
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

         // second scenario: read the json string
        $jsonNest = json_encode($arr, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

        return str_contains($jsonNest, '{'); // {} assoc, [] sequential
    }
```

#### NOTES

`php@8.1` is required, check out the [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/funder7/a306e78148bffdaf186da2bbc401a1cb) containing the unit test of this method + Polyfills (php>=7.3).

I've tested also [Hussard's posted solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864257/5871709), *A* & *B* are passing all tests, *C* fails to recognize: `{"1":0,"2":1}`.

##### BENCHMARKS

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Thinkscape/1965669#gistcomment-4029335) json parsing is *~200 ms* behind *B*, but still *1.7 seconds* faster than solution *C*!

What do you think about this version? Improvements are welcome!

Comment: `empty($arr)` can be safely replaced with the function-less equivalent `!$arr`.

Comment: does it cover empty string, and variable without a value cases?

Comment: `empty($v)` and `!$v` will both return `true` on a string with no length.  They both perform a loosely typed `false` check.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I thought that `empty()` was the most safe way to do this kind of check.

Comment: `!empty()` or `isset()` should ONLY be used if you need to check that the variable exists AND you want the secondary check that they provide.  `!empty()` checks that the variable exists and is not "falsey".  `isset()` checks that the variable exists and is not null.  There are many pages on Stack Overflow that explain the intricacies in excruciating detail.

Comment: By the way `str_contains()` is a very easy check to monkeywrench.  `$arr = ['one', 'two{'];`  Is it indexed?  Yes.  Does it contain a opening curly brace? Yes.  It breaks your script.  Perhaps just check the first byte of the string instead of the whole string.

Comment: Why does `in_array($value)` have any bearing on whether an array is associative/sequential?  I don't understanding your intention.  I'd recommend something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858728/2943403

Comment: it's related on how `foreach` works: even if the array is sequential, it will always have a `key` (numeric when sequential), and a value. Anyway probably you're right: I considered as sequential, any array of "simple" values, like `[1, 2, 3]` or `["a", "b", "c"]`, but `$value` may be a list of arrays, and still be considered as sequential. I must test this scenario! I think that the condition should be updated to `if(is_string($key) && is_array($value))`