# How do I fix this missing semicolon syntax error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, syntax-error

A friend wrote some code for me, and there was one file with a weird syntax error in it. After a bit of hunting, I narrowed it down to this section of code, which should reproduce the error:

```js
var say = functіon(message) {
  alert(message);
  return message;
};

say(say("Goodbye!"));
```

When I run this, I see an error in the Internet Explorer console that says `SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'`. I don't see a semicolon missing anywhere, and I can't imagine where it wants me to put one.

Where does it expect a semicolon and why does it expect a semicolon there?

Comment: You get an error in Firebug too: http://jsfiddle.net/AdHZY/

Comment: @tftd: Semicolons should only appear at the end of lines.  That would cause an error.

Comment: Script looks good. Is this the actual code?

Comment: That's weird. I've try your snippet in both IE and Chrome, all good.

Comment: You probably have a non-printable character in there somewhere which is breaking things.  Retype the code manually and it will work correctly. Copy/Pasting your code exactly produces errors, but manually entering it doesn't.

Comment: I thought this was an interesting problem, and I certainly learned something about how to troubleshoot it. I would certainly be puzzled if I encountered that error with code that visually looks right.

Comment: Someone has to be doing this to people on purpose...perhaps one of the online tools or something...someone thinks it is funny to randomly insert unicode characters which look like "normal characters"..how else could this happen?

Comment: It's a prank. Most definitively. Perhaps I am going to play this on someone.

Comment: I must say, I have the utmost respect for the OP checking their code in IE (at the time) since he knew that his website or script **would** look / work normally in any other browser with normal rendering / js capabilities :P

Comment: Well, the syntax highlighter of StackOverflow reveals it already: the `on` part of the word `function` is displayed in a different color.

Comment: For reference, the character is Unicode U+0456 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Your issue is the fact that the `i` in `functіon` is the Unicode character U+0456 `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I`. If you change it to a 'normal' `i` it should just work.

But now I'm wondering how the hack :) did you get a Cyrillic character there :P

[image: Screenshot of EditPlus showing the 'i' highlighted, with the status bar showing its codepoint, 0456]

Comment: @Rocket yup it is. Char `456`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you go about figuring out exactly what was wrong?

Comment: @CCCason It just had to be since the code looked ok. Just copy/pasted the code in a decent texteditor which displays the character codes. Could also have used a hex-editor if I wanted to be really cool ;)

Comment: @CCCason: Highlight the `i` in the question, right click, and select "seach".

Comment: i noticed it when i was looking at the snipped on jsfiddle. the selection box around the `і` was a little bigger than the other characters around it.

Comment: Which "decent texteditor" did you use? Notepad++ is the only one I can think of that would give me character codes (at least I think it does).

Comment: http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/ - on the left input one letter and it will be transformed into ascii. In this case the real `i=105` and the one here `i=1110`. I don't know if they are the right charcodes but that's usually the way you check.

Comment: I'm using editplus, but I think any decent texteditor will (or at least should) display it.

Comment: Yes, of coursed; as one of the other answers says, you get `funct?on` in Notepad++. Easy enough. I was still quite puzzled when I first ran it in JSFiddle, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish FWIW, VSCode can highlight non-ASCII characters. The settings are under `editor.unicodeHighlight`.

Answer (score 18):

You have misspelled the "function" :)

```
var say = function(message){
    alert(message);
    return message;
};

say(say("Goodbye!"));
```

You have inserted `functіon` :)

Comment: Visually, it's not misspelled. I suspect as @Rocket suggests one of the letters is another symbol in disguise.

Comment: @Rocket not in his case. He has a character that appears as normal but it's not. Even my IDE goes red with his code :)

Comment: its visually look different when i paste it on my vscode

Comment: This is an answer from 10 years ago. Most likely it's irrelevant today, but back in the days people used to do coding with Notepad++ and such errors weren't necessary obvious. :)

Answer (score 11):

I've copied and pasted it in my notepad++ and your code look like this. Retype your `function` keyword, i is replaced by ?.

```
var say = funct?on(message) {
  alert(message);
  return message;
};
say(say("Goodbye!"));
```

Answer (score 8):

I copied your code into jsfiddle, and Chrome too gives an error.  I deleted the word "function", and re-typed "function", and it worked fine.

There must be some extra character there.

Comment: There's no other explanation that makes sense. Demo of retyping `function`: http://jsfiddle.net/AdHZY/1/

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you inserted Cyrillic "i" instead of normal "i".
I get the fellow errors in VSCode:

- `',' expected. (1, 29)`
- `',' expected. (2, 10)`
- `Declaration or statement expected. (4, 3)`

You can try evaluating `"functіon" === "function"` as well:

```js
console.log("functіon" === "function")
```

However, when I try to compare it by drawing "function" myself, it returns true:

```js
console.log("function" === "function")
```

Also, I didn't include semicolons here; in javascript they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Verify with this page: https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=funct%D1%96on(message)

It displays information of each character.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the same error code when debugging someone else's work. To fix this I pasted the section of code into Notepad and then re-copied it back to Visual Studio.  The error went away.  I think whoever wrote the code originally must have copied it from somewhere with some strange characters in it.