# Verifying my code uses only ASCI | Checking with regex

Tags: javascript

IE9 is giving me an error that makes no sense on syntax. `missing )`

Previously it was `Expected ;` Previous SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474812/ie9-reports-missing-semicolon-that-exists)

I don't see random errors on any other Browser and my codes passes jslint.com and jshint.com

Want to verify there is no unicode that `snuck` into my code so I'm going to run it through regex and check for

```
[\x00-\x7F]
```

Is this a valid approach?

**Related**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Currently there's no way for us to tell whats wrong with your code if you don't share any of it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code...it is an IE issue...as I stated my code passes jslint.com and jshint.com...+ I can't see that IE is giving an accurate line number...so I wouldn't know what to post.

Comment: anyways...using regexpal.com gives an awesome view of my code in ASCI with color highlighting...just plop your code in one box and the regex I mentioned above in the other...and it hightlights it for you...pretty sure I have all ASCII.

Comment: Unicode is valid to use, but if you want to check for ASCII you should use `[\x09\x0a\x0c\x20-\x7e]*`. There are a lot of control characters below \x20 and I'm not sure how IE handle them.

Comment: This includes all the characters in my code: [\x0a\x20-\x7e]...don't need 09 or 0c

Comment: `\0x09` = tab, `\0x0a` = line feed, `\0x0d` = carriage return. The end of a line is usually marked as `\x0c\x0a`. It it almost a decade since I used IE for development so I might remember it wrong, but I think I ran into the problem that IE didn't like control characters below `\x20`. Depending on what editor you use, it is easy to insert control characters: just press `CTRL` and one of `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_` to get ASCII \x00 - 0x1f

Comment: I don't use tabs.....what is difference between line feed and carriage return?

Comment: some how my code still has returns in it without carriage returns or line feeds...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335334/symbolic-representation-of-return-x0a-vs-other

Comment: Sorry, replace `\0x0c` with `\x0d`. `\0x0c` is form feed.

Comment: I don't use tabs or carriage returns, or form feeds...

Comment: the only special character I need is 0a

Comment: If you have line feeds without using `\0x0a` or `\0x0d` it could be \u0085, \u2028 or \u2029.

Comment: I have not idea actually...thanks for the help!

Comment: What was the issue? Then I can write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was almost a decade ago since I developed in IE so my memory might be wrong, but I have a faint recollection that IE didn't like control characters in the code (characters below 0x20, except for line feed, carriage return and tab).

Depending on what editor you use, it is easy to insert control codes by pressing `CTRL` at the same time as one of `@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_` to get control code 0x00 - 0x1f.

If you want to use a regexp to validate that you only have printable ASCII and allowed control characters you could use `^[\x09\x0a\x0d\x20-\x7e]*$`. It allows tab (x09), line feed (x0a), carriage return (x0d) and all printable ASCII characters. Delete (x7f) is left out.

If you want to detect if you have something that isn't a printable ASCII or allowed control character, you can use `[^\x09\x0a\x0d\x20-\x7f]` to match for anything that isn't tab, line feed, carriage return or printable ASCII.

In Unicode there are some new line terminatos: next line (\u0085), Line Separator (\u2028) and Paragraph Separator (\u2029).

Many internet protocols (and vanilla text files on Windows systems) expect the end of a line to be indicated with carriage return followed by line feed (`\0x0d\0x0a`), something that is inherited from the days of printers where you wanted to be able to just return the carriage without advancing to the next line, to be able to write underscore for example. It could also be used to make the text a little bolder by printing the same line again, or print in gray scales...