# Symbolic representation of Return | \x0a vs. other

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to verify my code.

Here is a regex check on it with out 0xa:

[image]

As you can see at some places where there is a return character the regex does not match b.c. 0xa is used for the return character.

Here is a regex check inlcuding 0xa:

[image]

As you can see it is all included.

In short my .js includes these characters:

```
[\x0a\x20-\x7e]
```

However I am concerned as to why it sometimes uses a return as:

```
\\ the other return character ( have not verified yet )
```

and sometimes it uses a return as:

```
\x0a
```

**Related**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: regexpal doesn't show the color of `\x0a`. For example [vim](http://www.vim.org/) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised that it look like it groups the rows together, but it has to do with the star in your regexp. Change your regexp to `[\x20-\x7e]+`. Using the plus sign (one or more matches) instead of star (zero or more matches) I think you get the expected result.

If you want to see whats really is in the inputText-field on regexpal, open up the console in your browser and run `document.getElementById('inputText').value.replace(/[^\x20-\x7e]/g,function(a){‌​a = a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); return '\\u0000'.slice(0,6-a.length) + a;});` and you will get a true representation of the string.

Pretty print:

```
document.getElementById('inputText').value.replace(
  /[^\x20-\x7e]/g,
  function (a){‌
    ​a = a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    return '\\u0000'.slice(0,6-a.length) + a;
  }
);
```

Comment: might i ask how you became so knowledgeable with character codes and similar?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Sure, but I don't really know what to say... I'm curious, have read a lot of documentation, have worked with many different systems, and thinks logically. During the years I have done a lot of conversion from one code page to another (code pages was used in DOS (used before Windows) before Unicode was invented). One reason that I learned about different character sets from the beginning was that my native language has more than 26 characters in the alphabet, so it was always a bit problematic to send messages between different systems.

Comment: By the way, did you find what character it was that gave you problem?

Comment: 26 characters...is same number of keywords JavaScrtipt has....I think they did this for fun...I have not found the problem yet...once I do I will post...this has been going on for a while so I'm in no hurry...I'm targeting IE10 but 'practicing' on IE9...in preparation for the same issues.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist If you like, you can send the file to me (see my profile for email address). Pack it with zip or similar before to preserve every character in the source file.

Comment: Ok, so why did someone downvote this more than five years later, without a comment?