# Have I done something wrong, or is this a bug? (TypeScript/Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, typescript

## Resolved:

Thank you all for your help. I'm not sure exactly what caused this, but I restarted Visual Studio and everything went back to normal. Not sure why, but it's been working ever since (yesterday).

---

I didn't have these problems last night (with the same code - unchanged):

[image]

I don't see what the issue is.

The error I am getting is:

> JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 9 in [path/app.ts]
>   SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'.

What the deuce?!

Incase you can't see the image, the error is referring to this line:
`declare var document;`

**Update**

The javascript file which is a result of the TypeScript being compiled into JavaScript looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    start();
};
function sayHello(msg) {
    return msg = "Hello, therel ol!";
}
function start() {
    var element = document.getElementById("link");
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("response").innerText = sayHello("Hi");
    }, false);
    if(XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

And as you can see, everything looks fine. I don't get why it's throwing this error.

Comment: `declare` in javascript?

Comment: See my tags and Question title; it's TypeScript. :-) And yes, declare. 'Cause that's how you do it in TypeScript: http://www.typescriptlang.org/: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238

Comment: I've updated my question to show the resulting JavaScript code from the compiled ts file to help you understand. Even the javascript is fine.

Comment: @MitchS - In *Type*Script, `declare` is an Ambient Declaration.

Comment: It seems like a Javascript interpreter is trying to handle the "declare" line (hence the word "Javascript" in the error message) - which it should not because by the time it hits Javascript those lines are removed by TS, correct?  Is it possible that VS/TS thinks that your TS is actually JS?  Accidental copy/paste?

Comment: Interesting theory, @James - I am not sure - but I just tested the same code in Chrome, and Opera and the page works just fine. And after another Google search, I found a similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246051/how-do-i-fix-this-missing-semicolon-syntax-error-in-javascript - I'm not sure why it would think that it's JS. Ah, I'm not sure what you mean by "Accidental copy/paste" though. I write all the code manually, but pasted it into SO question

Comment: I keep finding the same questions scattered all over the web about this problem in IE, but the solutions seem to be due to hidden symbols or misspellings, which can be fixed by manually rewriting - which I've done and the problem still persists. :/

Comment: I just closed Visual Studio and restarted; rebuilt the site and debugged - now it's working again. Not sure what the problem was, but it's working now. Thanks @James

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 11):

My guess is that you have referenced the `app.ts` file on your page by mistake, when you should have referenced the `app.js` file.

I'm assuming you get this error when running your application, not at design time.

i.e.

```
<script src="app.ts"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's strange, I'm not sure that was the problem because I only had the .js file referenced.

Comment: I had this error when I included the .ts file in my page instead of the compiled .js, just like James Kent suggested.

Comment: My .ts file was erroneously included in an MVC bundle. I needed to wildcard *.js

Comment: thanks ! this was my issue by mistake i had added .ts file references in my bundle file. Once I change it to .js file it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to declare document - it should already be declared. It comes from the virtual lib.d.ts file which is referenced by default.

Try commenting out the declare line.

Comment: I assume you still have this problem? Firstly try downloading the WebEssentials VS extension which gives a lot of useful tools for TypeScript including a compile options page. One of the options in the compiler turns on/off the "document" type - it may be that is the issue. In my VS2012 I get intellisense on "document" from the virtual lib.d.ts file.

Comment: Thanks @Quango, I'm no longer experiencing this issue. I restarted Visual Studio and everything was fine again. I alrady had Web Essentials and all that installed. :)