# Retrieving Cell Values from an Excel Spreadsheet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

I am looking to retrieve cells from an excel spreadsheet using JavaScript, to use the values in an HTML page. Currently, I do not know how to use SheetJS, and I am not able to use it to parse the worksheets.

What I am looking to do is: Retrieve Cell A1 -> Create a variable with the value of cell A1

Could anyone help me access the worksheet from JS and then get the value from an XLSX sheet? I have to use Excel for the purpose of this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ReadData(cell, row) {
  var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
  var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\RS_Data\\MyFile.xls");
  var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
  var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell, row).Value;
  document.getElementById('div1').innerText = data;
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says: SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' Line 10:6, but all of the semi-colons are in the correct places?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246051/how-do-i-fix-this-missing-semicolon-syntax-error-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
You should try your path:
`excel.Workbooks.Open("C://RS_Data//MyFile.xls");`

// --> instead of --> \