# Inserting data from a single cell from an excel spreadsheet into a webpage

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to link a price on my webpage to a value in a cell in an Excel spreadsheet.  I found this javascript code as an answer to a similar post on stack overflow:

[Retrieving Cell Values from an Excel Spreadsheet using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873180/retrieving-cell-values-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-javascript)

```
    function ReadData(cell, row) {
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\RS_Data\\MyFile.xls");
    var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
    var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell, row).Value;
    document.getElementById('div1').innerText = data;
    }
```

"Book1.xlsx" is uploaded to my server at the same level as the webpage and I want to link cell C2 in Sheet1, so I've changed the code to this

```
    <div id="div1">
    <script> 
    function ReadData(cell, row) {
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("Book1.xlsx");
    var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
    var data = excel_sheet.Cells(1, 2).Value;
    document.getElementById('div1').innerText = data;
    }
    </script>
    </div>
```

However, I can't get it to work - nothing is displayed on the webpage.  Any help with this is much appreciated.  Please note that I'm a beginner at this when replying.

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: I inserted it in the <body> section of the webpage exactly as I wrote it above, assuming that would execute it. Is that not correct?

Comment: Since it's function you need to call it, for example you could call it from the onclick event of a button.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I want to call it on page load.  I've now added window.onload = ReadData;  before </script>  Is that correct?  (It's still not working)