# Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘∼’

Tags: haskell, gadt, type-families

I'm trying to compile a code snippet from Maguire's *Thinking with Types*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Expr_ a
    = (a ∼ Int) => LitInt_ Int
    | (a ∼ Bool) => LitBool_ Bool
    | (a ∼ Int) => Add_ (Expr_ Int) (Expr_ Int)
    | (a ∼ Bool) => Not_ (Expr_ Bool)
    | If_ (Expr_ Bool) (Expr_ a) (Expr_ a)
```

Using GHCi, version 8.10.4, I get the following:

```
λ> :l TypeEquality.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TypeEquality.hs, interpreted )

TypeEquality.hs:4:10: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘∼’
  |
4 |     = (a ∼ Int) => LitInt_ Int
  |          ^

TypeEquality.hs:5:10: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘∼’
  |
5 |     | (a ∼ Bool) => LitBool_ Bool
  |          ^

TypeEquality.hs:6:10: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘∼’
  |
6 |     | (a ∼ Int) => Add_ (Expr_ Int) (Expr_ Int)
  |          ^

TypeEquality.hs:7:10: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘∼’
  |
7 |     | (a ∼ Bool) => Not_ (Expr_ Bool)
  |          ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

**Is there a language pragma that will make this compile?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real problem was that I had copy-and-pasted the code from the book, and the `~` symbol was formatted as the **similar-but-not-identical `∼`**! I probably won't be the last person to make this mistake, so hopefully a search for the error message will bring someone to this post.

The following will compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Expr_ a
    = (a ~ Int) => LitInt_ Int
    | (a ~ Bool) => LitBool_ Bool
    | (a ~ Int) => Add_ (Expr_ Int) (Expr_ Int)
    | (a ~ Bool) => Not_ (Expr_ Bool)
    | If_ (Expr_ Bool) (Expr_ a) (Expr_ a)
```

Comment: Takeaway: _never_ copy&paste from a pdf document!

Comment: [Unicode strikes again!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246051/how-do-i-fix-this-missing-semicolon-syntax-error-in-javascript)

Comment: I recommend not copying if you can, when you write you necessarily spend more time on it and it leaves your mind free to wander and engage with the code. Like are the parentheses required around type equality? Wait if `a ~ Bool` could you then write `Not_ (Expr_ a)`? You'd be surprised how often you trigger compiler bugs or errors in the source materal with such thinking. Additionally it gets your fingers used to it like rote learning on the piano.