# JS 'error Missing semicolon semi' while using simple function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I am getting some error while executing simple function in JS.

```
let calls = function (){
    console.log('Testing');
}
calls();
```

Error :

> error  Missing semicolon  semi

```
Platform : windows 10,
Editor : VS code 1.68.0 
node  : v16.14.2
```

Above error gets fixed if I use `;` :

```
let calls = function (){
        console.log('Testing');
    };
    calls();
```

I can confirm `i` in `function` is correctly used & its not a special char as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246051/how-do-i-fix-this-missing-semicolon-syntax-error-in-javascript) post.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a linting error?

Comment: Works for me with Node v18.3.0, and I can't see any problems. Is this a linter function?

Comment: sure, thanks for your time tadman & zero298 ,  I will have a look.

Comment: For linting, do I need to disable /enable any specific rule so that it will not display error ? I am new to js & learning about it.