# Consistently iterate API response which may be an object or an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, types, foreach

I have the following JSON code.

```
{
  "Artikelnr":"1000",
  "Vooraad_NL":2.0,
  "Voorraad_DE":1.0,
  "Voorraad_BE":0.0
}
```

When I loop through the json with a foreach it loops 4 times. How can I make it loop only through the amount of articles. Like 1 article loops only once. When there are 3 articles in the json loop three times.

I use the following php code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ((isset($data) && $data != "") && (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)) {

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $articlenumber = $data['Artikelnr'];
    $voorraad_nl = $data['Vooraad_NL'];
    $voorraad_de = $data['Vooraad_DE'];
    $voorraad_be = $data['Vooraad_BE'];
}

}
```

Comment: Do you build the JSON? If so putting that in array would allow 1 loop. Otherwise can use `if($key != 'Artikelnr') { continue; }` if you only want loop to run on `"Artikelnr":"1000",` data point.

Comment: The JSON is send by the Microsoft API. When a product is sold on our website, the Microsoft Business Central API sends an update of the stock.

Comment: And it it sent like that or like `[{
  "Artikelnr":"1000",
  "Vooraad_NL":2.0,
  "Voorraad_DE":1.0,
  "Voorraad_BE":0.0
}]`? Like that all points would be content at one level. As is they are all at the same level. I don't see how they could send back 2 results at the same time with that structure

Comment: The did send it with the []. But now it's changed to the version I've posted. I don't get it. Before I could easily use $articlenumber = $data[$key]['Artikelnr'];

Comment: Going need to explain how it is being changed.

Comment: I've asked them if the send every stock update with a separate API call. So every product with a separate API call. I think that's the new solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change the second argument to json_decode to false. Then you can check to see whether `$data` is an object or an array of objects, and handle appropriately.

Comment: When i run your code with simple echo inside foreach it only loop, and echo each item just once

Comment: So you basically need to write a condition: [php is variable an array or object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10957100/2943403)  If your script requires an objectArray, but you have an object, you need to push the object into a parent array.  Your question is not crystal clear about the variable payloads that your application is receiving.  Please create a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

You have the following `json`

```
{
  "Artikelnr":"1000",
  "Vooraad_NL":2.0,
  "Voorraad_DE":1.0,
  "Voorraad_BE":0.0
}
```

So, when you looping it after `json_decode`, you are getting something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Artikelnr] => 1000
    [Vooraad_NL] => 2
    [Voorraad_DE] => 1
    [Voorraad_BE] => 0
)
```

So, when you are looping the $data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $articlenumber = $data['Artikelnr'];
    $voorraad_nl = $data['Vooraad_NL'];
    $voorraad_de = $data['Vooraad_DE'];
    $voorraad_be = $data['Vooraad_BE'];
}
```

The loop is iterating over the `$data` array which contains 4 items and you are not using the `$key/$val` inside your loop but the `$data` itself so your seeing the same items 4 times.

if you have only one `json` then you don't need to loop, you can simply do the same thing without the loop, for example:

```
echo $data['Artikelnr'];
echo $data['Vooraad_NL'];
echo $data['Voorraad_DE'];
echo $data['Voorraad_BE'];
```

If you are not sure whether the result is an array of objects or a single object, you may try something like this:

```
// Decode without passing the true in the json_encode
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

if (is_object($data)) {
    $data->Artikelnr;
    $data->Vooraad_NL;
    $data->Vooraad_DE;
    $data->Vooraad_BE;
} else {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $articlenumber = $item->Artikelnr;
        $voorraad_nl   = $item->Vooraad_NL;
        $voorraad_de   = $item->Vooraad_DE;
        $voorraad_be   = $item->Vooraad_BE;
    }
}
```

if you want to use each item as an array then you may convert the object (stdClass) using `(array)`, for example:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $item = (array) $item;
    // Now you can use the item as an array
    $articlenumber = $item['Artikelnr'];
    // ...
}
```

Same could be possible for the single object, for example:

```
if (is_object($data)) {
    $data = (array) $data;
    $articlenumber = $data['Artikelnr'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend conditionally converting any encountered objects to a objectArrays and unconditionally writing a loop to iterate the objectArray.

All applications should endeavor to stabilize their input/output data types for more streamlined scripting (a shame that the endpoint that you are hitting doesn't make this consideration).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/barTi))

```
$data = json_decode($response);
if (is_object($data)) {
    $data = [$data];
}
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    var_dump($obj);
}
```