# PHP - associative array as an object

Tags: php, class, object, yaml, associative-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Array to Object PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)

I'm creating a simple PHP application and I would like to use [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) files as a data storage. I will get the data as an associative array, with this structure for example:

```
$user = array('username' => 'martin', 'md5password' => '5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592')
```

However, I would like to extend the associative array with some functions and use the `->` operator, so I can write something like this:

```
$user->username = 'martin';  // sets $user['username']
$user->setPassword('hello'); // writes md5 of 'hello' to $user['md5password']
$user->save();               // saves the data back to the file
```

Is there a good way to do this without a class definition?

Basically, I would like to have JavaScript style objects in PHP :)

Comment: Should use at least sha1 these days.

Comment: +wesside 2016 update: BCrypt via password_hash or PBKDF2 with SHA512.

Comment: @mjsa way to look out!

Answer (score 52):

Just cast it:

```
$user = (object)$user;
```

Of course, there are other, more flexible solutions like creating a class that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php):

```
$user = new User(); // implements ArrayAccess

echo $user['name'];
// could be the same as...
echo $user->name;
```

Comment: Note that if $user is `null`, casting it to `(object)` will make it non-null (it will be an empty object). To avoid this you can do this: `$user = $user ? (object)$user : null`

Answer (score 9):

Literally just make a `$class = new stdClass;` and iterate and reassign.  Be aware this is only one level deep, just like typecasting.  You would have to write a recursive iterator to get it all.  From what I remember Kohana 2/3 has to_object() you can probably use.

Found it:

```
class Arr extends Kohana_Arr {

    public static function to_object(array $array, $class = 'stdClass')
    {
            $object = new $class;
            foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {
                    if (is_array($value))
                    {
                    // Convert the array to an object
                            $value = arr::to_object($value, $class);
                    }
                    // Add the value to the object
                    $object->{$key} = $value;
            }
            return $object;
    }
```

Comment: Note this will also convert sequential (non-associative) arrays to objects as well. You might want to combine with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254008/1074400