# php access property of object in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php variable that I got from a _POST.  var_dump shows this:

```
array(9) { [0]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "62"
["amount"]=> string(5) "10878" } [1]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "63"
["amount"]=> string(5) "10878" } [2]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "64"
["amount"]=> string(5) "10878" } [3]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "65"
["amount"]=> string(5) "10878" } [4]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "66"
["amount"]=> string(5) "10878" } [5]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "67"
["amount"]=> string(5) "28416" } [6]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "68" 
["amount"]=> string(5) "28416" } [7]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "69" 
["amount"]=> string(5) "28416" } [8]=> array(2) { ["age"]=> string(2) "70" 
["amount"]=> string(5) "28416" } }
```

I loop through the array but can't get the properties to print:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($incomeSched); $i++) {
    $age = $incomeSched[$i]->age;
    $amt = $incomeSched[$i]->amount;
    echo "age=$age, amount=$amt<br>";
}
```

age and amount are blank:

```
age=, amount=
```

Comment: Currently on mobile but have you tried $incomeSched[$i]['age']?

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between associative arrays and objects.

```
$incomeSched[$i]->age;
```

is what you'd do to access the property of an object. For an associative array you'd want

```
$incomeSched[$i]["age"]
```

You can cast an array as an object if need be:

```
$obj = (object)$incomeSched;
```

learn more here:

[PHP - associative array as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203074/php-associative-array-as-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `->age` is object syntax. You need array syntax which would be `['age']`.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($incomeSched); $i++) {
    $age = $incomeSched[$i]['age'];
    $amt = $incomeSched[$i]['amount'];
    echo "age=$age, amount=$amt<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  You are right but so was @Michael Beeson and he gave a little more info that will help others searching for this so I gave him the credit for the answer.