# PHP: Determining A Parameter Type

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Arrays: A good way to check if an array is associative or numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-numeric)

My one function's one parameter takes the values of following types:

```
null,

'*','',

array('domain1','domain2'),

array('domain1'=>'*','domain2'=>'group1','domain3'=>array('group1','group2')),
```

I have problems while I am trying to determine what kind of type the parameter. Especially, at determining if it is an array and its key parameters.

How can I determine the parameter type basically?

Comment: is_null(), is_array(), etc

Comment: @MarcB - That's wouldn't tell you whether it's an associative array.

Comment: @MarcB - that won't help him distinguish array 1 with array 2, which is his main concern.

Comment: Creating this question alone must have taken 5 times more time than googling "php get type" and feeling lucky.

Comment: @joseph: passing in arbitrary data/types as parameters in PHP means doing more work yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-numeric

Comment: @MarcB - Which is exactly why I marked this question as a duplicate of that other one you then linked to. All I'm saying is that RTMF does not apply here.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis - Again, searching Google for "php get type" would not help you distinguish between array types.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is_array` function to find out if the parameter is an array.would you give us your codes to give more details?

Answer (score 0):

PHP [gettype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) function should do what you want. For checking specific type you can use is_* functions like is_array. You can find info about them [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php).

Answer (score 0):

Php has a ton of functions for this.

[Here](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=is_%2a&scope=quickref) is a search with most (if not all) of these.

You will be using mostly functions that start with `is` (`is_array()`, `is_null()`, `isset()`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy one liner for determining type, you probably don't want to be using arrays at all. You might find that populating your data into an object of a specific class would be more useful.

Then you can test the object type with `instanceof` or `is_a()`.

Using an object would also give you the ability to provide additional functionality to the data structure. And it could still be treated as an array (eg with `foreach()`, etc) by making it an Iterator.

If you prefer to stick with arrays, and you want to distinguish between a keyed and a numeric array, you could check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-numeric).

The best answer there was a short function along the following lines:

```
function array_isassoc(array $array) {
    return array_keys($array) !== range(0,count($array)-1);
}
```

This will return `true` for a keyed array or `false` for a numeric array.

It's probably the most reliable method you could use, although it will stop working if you have a numeric array and remove elements from it without renumbering the keys.

Comment: The array_isassoc() function will not work for an enumerated array with non-contiguous keys - if there's any gaps in the sequence, it will fail

Comment: @MarkBaker - Why are we having this conversation all over again? Go bash [the original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-numeric#answer-173479), and mark this question as a duplicate. Oh, and while you're there, you can upvote [the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/php-arrays-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-array-is-associative-or-numeric/4254008#4254008).

Comment: @JosephSilber - to be fair, I did state that my preferred solution here is not to use an array at all, but a properly considered class structure. That isn't an answer on the other question because the other question is more direct about what it's asking. I only added the isassoc part of the answer for completeness, and I did reference the previous question when I did so. (having said all that, my guess is that the OP will go with a solution of that type rather than redo everything to use objects; it's probably a more pragmatic option if what he's got nearly works anyway)