# Check what kind of array this is via php

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a simple way to see if this array:

`array('apples', 'bananas');`

is associative or not, that is `key=>value`. Now PHP will give you something like:

```
array(2){
    [0]=>'apples'
    [1] => 'bananas'
}
```

if you `var_dump` the above array. So in theory I have my associative array. But what I am looking for is to see if `array('key' => 'some value', 'some_other_key' => 'some other value');` is a "true" associative array or if its just a regular array.

I have seen a couple posts on this through out stack but a lot of their answers are really complicated or poorly written or not even OO at all.

Comment: So why don't you tell us what you saw and how it wasn't good enough?

Comment: What is the difference between a truly associative array and regular? PHP knows only that one array, if you do not count instances of SplFixedArray.

Comment: What you have is an enumerated array, not an associative array: if the keys were strings, then it would be an associative array

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to differentiate between purely numeric-keyed arrays v.s. string-keyed?

```
$string_keys = preg_grep('/\D/', array_keys($your_array));
if (count($string_keys) > 0) {
   echo "at least one non-numeric key - it\'s associative";
} else {
   echo "no non-numeric keys. it's a normal array";
}
```

in short: grab all the keys in the array, use the preg_grep function to search for NON-digits in the resulting array-of-keys. If you get a non-zero count of matching keys, you've got an associative array.

Comment: So `array('key' => 'value')` will echo `"at least one non-numeric key - it\'s associative";` if I understand this correctly?

Comment: This does not recognize "holes" in the array, see: http://codepad.org/3UYjy0Ht ([This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4254008/603003) provides a better way.)

Comment: @comfreek: OP didn't demand that the array be consecutively indexed... just whether it's associative or not. sparse array are perfectly legal in PHP and many other languages.

Comment: @MarcB It's a bit picky but your function also thinks `array( '0' => 'Value' )` is numeric.

Comment: `'0' == 0` is TRUE in PHP, so yes... it is a numerically keyed array

Comment: Hmm... I see indeed. A little playing around and PHP automatically converts the string '0' to int when used as array key. I would've thought it kept the type regardless, which would be `'0' !== 0`. (This is from a quick `foreach( $array as $key => $value ){ var_dump( $key ); }` so if my observations are skewed give me a heads up.)

Comment: php has "lazy" comparisons, `==`, `!=` which only compare values after one's been type coerced to match the other, and strict comparison, `===`, `!==` which compare type AND value. `'0' == 0` is true, but `'0' === 0` is false