# How can I keep only every second element from array usign PHP?

Tags: php

Below is a part of my produced array. How can I keep only every second element usign PHP?

I have tried this until now without luck, maybe it depends on the structure of the array, I didn't understand.

```
$size = count($array);
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 2) {
  $result[] = $array[$i];
}
var_dump($result);
```

this is my array below:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                                        11.490
                [1] => 
                                        11.490
                [2] => 
                                        13.490
                [3] => 
                                        13.490
                [4] => 
                                        17.490
                [5] => 
                                        17.490
                [6] => 
                                        20.990
                [7] => 
                                        20.990
                [8] => 
                                        14.290
                [9] => 
                                        14.290
                [10] => 
                                        14.490
                [11] => 
                                        14.490
                [12] => 
                                        19.990
                [13] => 
                                        19.990
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The code I used is preg_match_all and I don't believe you need it since I provide the result of an array

Comment: Every other or unique? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Now here's an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) if you ever saw one.

Comment: @chris85 every other, thank you

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have added what I tried so far, you can remove your downvote if you like

Comment: You could probably get `preg_match_all` to return it the way you want.

Comment: Probably the best solution would be to FIX the way you create this array rather than trying to frig the array after the initial mistake

Comment: your code isn't terribly wrong per se; but obviously the array you are trying to filter has another array inside it. try: `$result[] = $array[0][$i]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access N-th element of an array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825281/how-to-access-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-php)

Comment: How do you know it's not working as you would expect? By any chance were you expecting the result to contain ` [0] => 11.490` and then `[2] => 11.490` instead of `[0]` and then `[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_filter (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
function odd($var)
{
    return($var & 1);
}

$array[0] = array_filter($array[0], "odd", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

EDIT:
Of course you can also use an "even" method

EDIT 2:
Change to match the code from the op.
*From $array to $array[0]*

EDIT 3:
Add a missing semicolon

Comment: while this is not wrong, wont work with his input. it's a nested array.

Comment: Then you pass $array[0] as a parameter

Comment: put it in your answer?

Comment: Hi. You need at least php 5.6 to use the flag *ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY*.  
If it doesn't work it also don't know the answer. But check out the php.net link for more informations on array_filter().

Answer (score -5):

How about using `unset` on every other element?

```
<?php
$array = array('1','1','2','2','4','4','5','5');

for($i = count($array) - 1; $i > 0; $i -= 2){
    unset($array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: `array_unique` removes all duplicate, while he wants to remove only every other element. Using `array_unique` could therefore remove too many values.

Comment: But if you look at your code, it will only process HALF the array, and then reduce that by a half. So your result will be one quarter of the array

Comment: Right, fixed. 
Note that the new solution will only work if the array has an even number of elements. Otherwise, `$i` should start at `count($array)-2`.

Comment: `$i > 0 / 2` ? That's interesting.

Comment: Did you test it. I DID! And that does not work either. The array is unchanged

Comment: I also did :)  
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32bde617876abbcce738ffea6d287549d51ac673