# How can I Iterate through PHP multi-dimension array that has label -> value structure

Tags: php, arrays

New to PHP (from C#). I have an array ($metaarray), which if I json_encode() to the screen, it has this value:

```
[
{
    "measure":"Walking","record":"steps","latestres":"6870","datet":"2022-08-31"
},{
    "measure":"","record":"kilograms","latestres":"117","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"","record":"","latestres":null,"datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Walking","record":"steps","latestres":"6840","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Bodyweight","record":"kilograms","latestres":"92","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Benchpress","record":"kilograms","latestres":"90","datet":"2022-09-12"
}
]
```

Is there an easy way for me to iterate through the metaarray - or to easily reference a record - eg. I would normally do something like:

```
    $latestres = $metaarray[0][2];
```

...which should be "6870" - however it doesn't return any result when I do that.

Is there a way I can easily reference a particular value (eg. first record, "latestres" or 3rd value) in the above array?

Comment: Well thats an array of Objects if that helps

Comment: Have you tried **foreach** and counting them? PHP arrays are a little surprising when you come from any other language.

Comment: `$metaarray[0]["lastestres"]`

Comment: Or better still `$metaarray[0]->lastres`

Comment: Or show us the array before you made a JSONString of it, thats a PHP data type and is processable in PHP so start there.

Comment: Show us a `var_export($array_before_you_JSONified_it);`

Comment: If you have an array already, why `json_encode()` further, as it will produce a JSON string. On the other hand, if you have the string, then do a `json_decode()`. The second parameter of `json_decode` will decide if it should produce an array or object. Once you get either an object or array, you can easily iterate (its easier to iterate an array tough). Now in case of array, the first level is index based and each index will be an associative array (key based)... so you will have to access like `$arr[$index][$key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but `$data[2]` does not represent third item in an array, unless the array happens to be created linearly (called a list). In PHP, `2` is actually the key to a map (name/value pair). So unless there is actually a key with that index, you can't access it. You can see a demo of what I'm talking about [here](https://3v4l.org/0Ab2K).

You can get around the feature/limitation by using one of the tricks from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24825397/231316

```php
function getNthItemFromArray(array $array, int $idx)
{
    return $array[array_keys($array)[$idx]];
}
```

Obviously you'd add some guards.

As everyone notes, you should really start with your data *before* the encode. However, assuming that for whatever you have a JSON string, you can tell the decoder to give you an associative array instead of an object. Putting that all together you could do something like:

```php
$json = <<<EOT
[
{
    "measure":"Walking","record":"steps","latestres":"6870","datet":"2022-08-31"
},{
    "measure":"","record":"kilograms","latestres":"117","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"","record":"","latestres":null,"datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Walking","record":"steps","latestres":"6840","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Bodyweight","record":"kilograms","latestres":"92","datet":"2022-09-12"
},{
    "measure":"Benchpress","record":"kilograms","latestres":"90","datet":"2022-09-12"
}
]
EOT;

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

echo getNthItemFromArray($decoded[0], 2);

function getNthItemFromArray(array $array, int $idx)
{
    return $array[array_keys($array)[$idx]];
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/POdma

Comment: Thank you - and to everyone else who helped too.