# Validating Array Keys in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following input form structure upon submission :

```
array:6 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "h7hb0yLzdYaFY0I4e1I7CQK7Niq9EqgXFTlramn9"
  "candidate" => array:4 [▶]
  "languages" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "ga"
    1 => "no"
    2 => "sk"
  ]
  "availabilities" => array:2 [▼
    "z" => array:1 [▶]
    2 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
  "experiences" => array:3 [▶]
]
```

I am trying to validate the 'availabilities' array keys to make sure they correspond to existing id's in the database:

```
'availabilities' => 'required|integer|exists:days_of_week,id',
```

If I use this rule it targets the main array, but the `exists` key is passing validation even when I use the browser console to change the id to something like 'z'. It fails on the `integer` rule because it retrieves an array as well. How does one validate array keys?

The [following example](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/form-array-validation-in-laravel-5-2) uses a similar form structure. But it does not cover how the employee id could be validated. I saw people add an 'id' key along with 'name' and 'age' for example and to have a rule against that 'id' field, but it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by adding a custom validator. See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules.

For example:

```
\Validator::extend('integer_keys', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return is_array($value) && count(array_filter(array_keys($value), 'is_string')) === 0;
});
```

You can then check the input with:

```
'availabilities' => 'required|array|integer_keys',
```

Found the array check here: [How to check if PHP array is associative or sequential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential/4254008#4254008)

Comment: As of Laravel 5.5. you can also add such rule directly as a closure: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures

Answer (score 12):

If you have control over the input data structure, I suggest to modify it to the following:

```js
  [
  ...,
  "availabilities" => [
    {
      "id": "z",
      "data" : [0 => "foo"]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "data" : [0 => "bar"]
    }
  ]
```

]

Then adjust your validation rules, to validate against your database for example

```php
public function rules {
    return [
        'availabilities' => 'filled',
        'availabilities.*.id' => 'required|integer|exists:days_of_week,id',
        'availabilities.*.data' => 'required|array'
        // etc...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Jurriën Dokter 's answer is a work around and uses PHP functions not Laravel rules, It works but if you really want to benefit from Laravel validation rules you have to tweak the validation request a little bit. Here's how:
Make a custom request:

```
php artisan make:request NameOfRequest
```

Place the following function in the request:

```php
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'availabilities_ids' => array_keys($this->get('availabilities'))
    ]);
}
```

In the rules:

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // place your other rules here .. 
            'availabilities'       => 'required|array|min:1',
            'availabilities.*'     => 'array',
            'availabilities_ids'      => 'exists:App\Models\Availability,id'
        ];
    }
```

This way you get the benefit of using Laravel's native validation rules through modifying the request params before validation.
See this link to know more about `prepareForValidation` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#prepare-input-for-validation