# php function to output indexed and associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need a PHP function to output any associative or indexed array.
I have an example of an associative array and a function I have created.

```
function print_assoc_array(){

$cars = array(

array('Car_brand' => 'Ford', 'Model' => 'Focus', 'Age' => '5 years'),              
array('Car_brand' => 'Skoda', 'Model' => 'Octavia', 'Age' => '3 years')              

);

foreach ($cars as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['Car_brand'] . " " . $value['Model'] . " " . $value['Age'] . "<br/>";
}
}

print_assoc_array();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how about `print_r()`?

Comment: I dont quite understand your problem.. It outputs as it shoud:

Ford Focus 5 years
Skoda Octavia 3 years

Comment: in this case it is an associative array. But I want the function to also be able to output an indexed array - that is my question :)

Comment: So check if array is associative or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential?rq=1