# how to process my array to be associative on first two levels and on third to have simple value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to construct an array where there only strings and the array would look like this
key->key->value

To explain it I attached two screenshots below.

I start with this:
[image]

After my code below I'm 90% there, yet there is an array in value on the third level instead of simple value.

[image]

Here is some code:

```
    $theme = ThemeHandler::with('sections.settings')->find($activeTheme);
    $themeSettings = $theme->sections;
    $themeSettings = collect($themeSettings->toArray());

    // dd($themeSettings);

    $themeSections = [];
    foreach ($themeSettings as $key => $value) {
        $settings = collect($value['settings']);
        $settings = $settings->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
            return [$item['key'] => $item['value']];
        });
        $themeSections[$value['key']] = $settings->toArray(); 
    }
    dd($themeSections);
```

I would like to end up with this structure

key->key->value

and not

key->key->single_element_array->value

I'm not sure how I end up with an array at the bottom level when I do this

```
return [$item['key'] => $item['value']];
```

inside the mapToGroups, which is a function found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-maptogroups

Maybe I misunderstand how mapToGroups work. Anybody has an idea how to get key->key->value structure output?

Comment: `$item['value']` is most likely an array at that point, which is why its returning an array. If its always going to be a single item array you can do `return [$item['key'] => ( ( is_array( $item['value'] ) ) ? $item['value'][0] : $item['value'] )];`

Comment: I know my data, $item['value'] is a simple value. Somehow mapToGroup turns it into an array and puts the value there as the only item.

Comment: This may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173400/how-to-check-if-php-array-is-associative-or-sequential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mapWithKeys()` instead of `mapToGroups()`.

You're getting an array instead of the simple value you expect because the value is a group, albeit a group with only one member.

`mapToGroups()` groups all the values with the same key, but `mapWithKeys()` will assign a single value to each key.

You can see in the examples in the collection documentation, [`mapToGroups()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-maptogroups) produces a result like this:

```
[
    'Sales' => ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'],
    'Marketing' => ['Johnny Doe'],
]
```

And [`mapWithKeys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-mapwithkeys) result is like this:

```
[
    'john@example.com' => 'John',
    'jane@example.com' => 'Jane',
]
```

Comment: hmm I will try that, you are right value somehow turns into array because mapToGroups works that way?

Comment: I got it working, two nested mapWithKeys did the trick, there are no extra arrays inserted now between levels. You literally saved me a few hours of headache! :) Much obliged! I also got rid of the foreach, two mapWithKeys are more elegant.