# how to cast an xml object to a associative array?

Tags: php, xml

I am doing some geocoding with the google api and was wondering how do i cast the returned simplexml object? I tried the following but it does no cast the child objects.. ie.. i would like a multi dimensional array.

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$adr."
&sensor=false";

$result = simplexml_load_file($url);

$result = (array) $result;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: adr; Notice: Undefined variable: result

Comment: well done.. its for context of the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99350/passing-php-associative-arrays-to-and-from-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a JSON request rather than XML; it's recommended; unless your application requires it. Then use:

```
json_decode( $result, true );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

I found very useful this function for converting Object to Array recursively:

http://forrst.com/posts/PHP_Recursive_Object_to_Array_good_for_handling-0ka

Adapted from the site above, to use it outside classes:

```
function object_to_array($obj) {
        $arrObj = is_object($obj) ? get_object_vars($obj) : $obj;
        foreach ($arrObj as $key => $val) {
                $val = (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) ? object_to_array($val) : $val;
                $arr[$key] = $val;
        }
        return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Turn the `SimpleXMLElement` object into json and decode the json string again into an associative array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result), 1);
```

The simple cast to array does not go more deep in there, that's why the trick via `json_encode` and `json_decode` is used.

Comment: @ChrisMccabe: Not with my PHP version, see as well http://php.net/json_decode - but maybe you have got some PHP that does not have that second parameter of `json_decode` or probably more realistic: some esoteric compile that inverts the seconds parameters meaning ;)