# What is the best php DOM 2 Array function?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, domdocument

I want to parse xml files,
The best way I found is to use DOMDocument() class so far.

sample xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<response>
<resData>
<contact:infData xmlns:contact="http://example.com/contact-1.0">
<contact:status s="value1"/>
<contact:status s="value2"/>
<contact:status s="value3"/>
<contact:status s="value4"/>
</contact:infData>
</resData>
</response>
```

I use function dom2array (bellow) to parse dom, but it only return 1 element (value4 only)

```
<?php
    function dom2array($node) {
    $res = array();
    if($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE){
       $res = $node->nodeValue;
    }else{
       if($node->hasAttributes()){
           $attributes = $node->attributes;
            if(!is_null($attributes)){
               $res['@attributes'] = array();
               foreach ($attributes as $index=>$attr) {
                   $res['@attributes'][$attr->name] = $attr->value;
               }
           }
       }
       if($node->hasChildNodes()){
           $children = $node->childNodes;
           for($i=0;$i<$children->length;$i++){
               $child = $children->item($i);
               $res[$child->nodeName] = dom2array($child);
           }
       }
    }
    return $res;
    }
?>
```

Is there any way to parse all xml elements and sent them to an array?

output array:

```
Array
(
[response] => Array
    (
        [#text] => 

        [resData] => Array
            (
                [#text] => 

                [contact:infData] => Array
                    (
                        [#text] => 

                        [contact:status] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [s] => value4
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Where is value1, value2, value3 ? :(
Thank you

Comment: Check the [xml2array function here](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Passing PHP associative arrays to and from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99350/passing-php-associative-arrays-to-and-from-xml)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use this (based on: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#93717);

```
function xml_to_array($root) {
    $result = array();

    if ($root->hasAttributes()) {
        $attrs = $root->attributes;
        foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
            $result['@attributes'][$attr->name] = $attr->value;
        }
    }

    if ($root->hasChildNodes()) {
        $children = $root->childNodes;
        if ($children->length == 1) {
            $child = $children->item(0);
            if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                $result['_value'] = $child->nodeValue;
                return count($result) == 1
                    ? $result['_value']
                    : $result;
            }
        }
        $groups = array();
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if (!isset($result[$child->nodeName])) {
                $result[$child->nodeName] = xml_to_array($child);
            } else {
                if (!isset($groups[$child->nodeName])) {
                    $result[$child->nodeName] = array($result[$child->nodeName]);
                    $groups[$child->nodeName] = 1;
                }
                $result[$child->nodeName][] = xml_to_array($child);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Test;

```
$s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <response>
            <resData foo="1">
                <contact:infData xmlns:contact="http://example.com/contact-1.0" bar="1">
                    <contact:status s="value1"/>
                    <contact:status s="value2"/>
                    <contact:status s="value3"/>
                    <contact:status s="value4"/>
                </contact:infData>
            </resData>
        </response>';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($s);
$xmlArray = xml_to_array($xml);
print_r($xmlArray);
// print_r($xmlArray['response']['resData']['contact:infData']['contact:status'][0]['@attributes']['s']);
// foreach ($xmlArray['response']['resData']['contact:infData']['contact:status'] as $status) {
    // echo $status['@attributes']['s'] ."\n";
// }
```

Comment: Very nice function - however it fails with CDATA section.  I changed `if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE)` to `if (in_array($child->nodeType,[XML_TEXT_NODE,XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE]))`

Comment: I get a bunch of (unnecessary?) empty `#text` keys -- http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26e649132b340af0dfc9953f6c2de1433bb9f8c8

Comment: To remove the empty `#text` keys, add the following in the beginning of the `foreach $children` loop:  `if($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE && empty(trim($child->nodeValue))) continue;`

Comment: @drzaus `empty(trim("0"))`  will remove "0"   use `trim($child->nodeValue) === ''`