# xml php DOM get each parent node from loop

Tags: php, xml, loops, dom, foreach

I have Xml file like

```
<tag>
    <item>
        <id>106</id>
        <title>DG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>105</id>
        <title>AC</title>
    </item>
</tag>
```

How to put each item id and title tags names to separate array

```
<?php
$xml = '<tag>
    <item>
        <id>106</id>
        <title>DG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>105</id>
        <title>AC</title>
    </item>
</tag>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
// $dom->load('xml.xml');
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$ExTagsArr = array();
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item/*') as $i=>$ExTagArr) {
$ExTagsArr[]=$ExTagArr->nodeName;

print_r($ExTagsArr);
}
```

i got strange arrays

> Array (
>       [0] => id ) Array (
>       [0] => id
>       [1] => title ) Array (
>       [0] => id
>       [1] => title
>       [2] => id ) Array (
>       [0] => id
>       [1] => title
>       [2] => id
>       [3] => title )

but i need get only

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => title
)
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => title
)
```

Comment: just use `$i` no need for that `if` statement, then just concatenate `$i` on `echo`

Comment: oh okay, so you're trying to target each item children. quite confusing, anyways glad it turned out well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$xml = '
<tag>
    <item>
    <id>106</id>
    <title>DG</title>
    </item>
    <item>
    <id>105</id>
    <title>AC</title>
    </item>
</tag>
';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// Using SimpleXML
$root = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
foreach ($root->xpath('//item') as $item) {
    $a = (array) $item;
    var_dump($a);
}

// Using plain DOM
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('item') as $item) {
    $a = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $item->childNodes->length; ++$i) {
        $child = $item->childNodes->item($i);
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $a[$child->tagName] = $child->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    var_dump($a);
}
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14554381/1478566) answer.

Comment: it simpleXml but i need Dom

Comment: its ok but why you use `if ($child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {` ? `iget ["id"]=>string(3) "106"` how to remove type param `string(3)` ?

Comment: Because that space between tags (`<item>` and `<id>`) is actually `XML_TEXT_NODE`. Also, there can be a comment. When working with DOM you need to take this details into account. In order to get just keys (`id`, and `type`) use `array_keys($a)`.

Comment: please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085473/xml-dom-appendchild-from-loop-array