# PHP - Soap Server: get attribute from SOAP request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm running a PHP SoapServer. This is a example of a request I can get in my request body:

```
<MyFunctionRequest>
    <Item>
        <Param Attr="XX">Value</Param>
    </Item>
</MyFunctionRequest>
```

The problem is, I can't seem to be able to read the attribute Attr in my SoapServer function. If I print the parameters I get in my SoapServer function, I get this:

```
StdClass Object
(
    [Item] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Param] => Value
    )
)
```

My SoapServer is built like this:

```
<?php
class MySoapServer {
    public function index() {
        $server = new SoapServer($pathToWsdl);
        $server->addFunction(array('MyFunction'));
    }
}

function MyFunction($params) {
    log(print_r($params, true));
    // function code, need the attribute Attr somewhere in here
}
```

So how can I get the attribute Attr in my function code? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same problem

Comment: I eventually worked around it by getting the raw request XML as a string using:

`$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Then I extracted the attribute from that string.

Comment: Yep, I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66821464/372215

I just had this issue and found this solution...

*Php Soap Server (under the hood) does not parse out the attributes.*

## parse data with DOMDocument to get all attributes

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

### convert to array for easy use...

[What is the best php DOM 2 Array function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553547/what-is-the-best-php-dom-2-array-function/14554381#14554381)

### results

```
  "MyFunctionRequest" => array:1 [
    "Item" => array:1 [
      "Param" => array:2 [
        "@attributes" => array:1 [
          "Attr" => "XX"
        ]
        "_value" => "Value"
      ]
    ]
  ]
```