# zend soap server reading xml attributes

Tags: php, xml, web-services, zend-framework, soap

need some help with `Zend_Soap_Server`. I am building a webservice to proccess certain fixed xml documents. The issue is that some of the nodes have data set in attributes:

```
<Car_Interest xmlns="http://schemas.multi-mit.com/DataFormat">
   <Model_Of_Interest Code="SOME CAR" />
   <Estimated_Purchase_Date>20190509</Estimated_Purchase_Date>
</Car_Interest>
```

When I pass the soap request in to server my handler class receives a `stdObject` with all nodes and values, but does not contain attributes. Here is my controller:

```
indexAction(){
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server(null,
        array('uri' => 'http://some.url/index/soap'));

    // set SOAP service class
    $server->setClass('Module_Model_SoapHandler');

    // handle request
    $server->handle($data);
}
```

And the handler so far:

```
class Testdrive_Model_SoapHandler {

    public function saveSubmission($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
...
```

The `$data` variable is passed in correctly (stdObject), but it does not include attribute values (arrtibute `Code` of node `Model_Of_Interest` . Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, have u found an aswer for this?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not, for my case I created the pre-processor that extracts attributes and than pass them as a seperate attribute array. Not the best solution, but it was a time limited project so I could not stay on this issue for too long.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue and found this solution...

*Php Soap Server (under the hood) does not parse out the attributes.*

## parse data with DOMDocument to get all attributes

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

### convert to array for easy use...

[What is the best php DOM 2 Array function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553547/what-is-the-best-php-dom-2-array-function/14554381#14554381)

### results

```
  "Car_Interest" => array:2 [
    "Model_Of_Interest" => array:1 [
      "@attributes" => array:1 [
        "Code" => "SOME CAR"
      ]
    ]
    "Estimated_Purchase_Date" => "20190509"
  ]
```

Comment: Solution works for me. Thanks for contributing to the community with your humble opinion