# PHP, xdom, php namespace and lowercase

Tags: php, xpath

**Hi,**

So, I'm working with PHP and Xdom, and I have these 2 expressions:

```
$parsed_node->meta->author                      = $node->xdom->query('//meta[@name="author"]/@content')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$parsed_node->meta->language                    = $node->xdom->query('//meta[@name="language"]/@content')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Of course, both of them, work perfectly fine, as long as the author of the website, didn't decide to use capital letters in the meta tag.

Now, when it comes to some websites, you'll see expressions like this:

```
<meta name="LANGUAGE" content="es" />
<meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="Global" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="all" />
<meta name="author" content="Clarin.com" />
<meta name="Classification" content="noticias, información, videos, diario, newspaper" />
```

So, as you can see, we have some names in uppercase, some in lowercase, and some of them with the first letter capitalised.

1. language in uppercase,
2. distribution in uppercase,
3. robots in uppercase
4. author in lowercase
5. and classification with the first letter capitalised.

So, as I'm using PHP and there's no such thing as xpath 2.0 I had no other option than to include PHP functions:

```
$node->xdom->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$node->xdom->registerPhpFunctions();
```

And then we can use an expression like this one:

```
$parsed_node->meta->language                    = $node->xdom->query("//meta[contains(php:functionString('strtolower', @name), 'language')]/@content")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Here comes my 2 questions

- does anyone knows a smaller expression I can use here?
- how would you apply the same expression to get the title case-insensitive?

  $parsed_node->title = $node->xdom->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue;

kind regards, chris.

Comment: For Godsake, please someone do a library for xdom 2.0 for PHP

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553547/what-is-the-best-php-dom-2-array-function

Comment: Thanks Robbie, but how is it related? are you suggesting me to use this custom function "xml2array()"? I'm complaining about lack of case-insensitivity on PHP Xdom implementation. Because the best approach I can think so far, is to lower-case the whole xdom, before doing the lookups

Comment: which is what you're trying to say...? To parse the whole node document, node by node and with a custom function and lowercase the tags only?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, either way @Robbie Averill gave me a super crypted answer, or I had an interesting idea while reading Robbie's recommendation.

The approach would be to make an altered version of those functions in the post, or to use those functions directly, to lookup the dom in an array, using PHP common array searching functions instead of xdom selectors... I'll write the function in case I can't find it.

Comment: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive Thanks @Robbie